# Why is my python executable crashing but runs fine prior to building?

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm trying to build a set of python files into a single executable with PyInstaller but I'm running into some run-time errors.
The code runs fine before building into the executable.

The main libraries I'm using are PyQt6(6.5.2) and arcgis. As mentioned this works fine in my editor but as a .app it results in:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcgis.gis._impl._portalpy'

Is there something I'm doing wrong with PyInstaller to package the python libraries?

(Intel Mac OSX)

Built the executable with
`PyInstaller main.spec`

With the following spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)
```

Comment: Is it possible that your pathex needs to be extended with some custom path that is part of your editor's environment, but not of the shell's that you wish to run the pyinstaller output from?